# Ruled surface defined by a Exponential map

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I have a regular curve $\alpha(s)$ on a 3-D Riemannian Manifold, with Frenet frame $\{T,N,B \}$. I define a surface now as

$$X_N(s,t) = exp_{\alpha(s)}(tN(\alpha(s)))$$

$exp_p$ being the exponential map at $p \in M$. I think the surface is a ruled surface atleast in $\mathbb R^3$. Can anyone tell me whether it will be something similar in a general case, in particular for $\mathbb S^3$ and the 3-D Hyperbolic plane equipped with the Poincare metric??

Also in case of $\mathbb R^3$, I have $X_N(s,t) = \alpha(s) + t N(\alpha(s))$, I dont know whether the sum makes sense as $N(s)$ need not be in $\mathbb R^3$?? So should I be seeing the whole thing in $\mathbb R^4$ ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is ruled, in the sense that it is fibered by geodesics. You need to assume that the tangent to $\alpha$ is nowhere parallel, $\nabla_T T\neq 0$, so that $N=\nabla_T T/\|\nabla_T T\|$ makes sense. Your formula $X_N(s,t) = exp_{\alpha(s)}(tN(\alpha(s)))$  then defines an immersed surface, at least in a neighborhood of $t=0$, fibered by the geodesics $s=const.$.

Comment: I had almost given up hope. Thanks a lot, but could you elaborate a bit more as to how it is an immersion in $\mathbb R^4$?? Also,I was asking whether that sum makes sense as $\alpha(s)$ is a point on M for each s whereas $N(\alpha(s)) $ may be in  the codimension space of M and is a vector??I am missing something simple maybe, but still cant see it.

Comment: Your formula  $X_N(s,t) = exp_{\alpha(s)}(tN(\alpha(s)))$ has nothing to do with $\mathbb R^4$, it is intrinsic to $M$. For $M=\mathbb R^3$ the exponential map is given simply by $exp_x(v)=x+v$, hence $X_N(s,t) = \alpha(s) + t N(\alpha(s))$. But in general you cannot write the exponential map so simply.

Comment: Yes I realise that. But that $v$ should be in $T_p(M)$ right?

Comment: Yes, $exp_p$ is defined $T_pM\to M$.

Comment: But then $N(\alpha(s))$ may be(not always) in $T_p(M)^{\perp}$, or am I wrong about that?

Comment: So I think I misunderstood your original question. What do you mean by the Frenet frame of a curve in a 3-dim riemannian manifold? You didnt mention any embedding of $M$ anywhere, so I took it to mean the following: $T=\dot \alpha/\|\dot\alpha\|$, $N=\nabla_T T/\|\nabla_T T\|$, $B=T\times N$ (assuming $M$ is oriented, so vector product makes sense).

Comment: I think it would be more prudent to look at $M$ in $E^4$ as they are later supposed to have constant sectional curvatures. Though the above question does not assume that.But what you assumed does make sense to me actually.

Comment: But in general when one talks of a Normal to a surface it should be in $T_p(M)^{\perp}$ right? Would that normal be $B(\alpha(s))$ here?

Comment: No, it all happens in $M$ (or rather $TM$). I cannot make any other sense of your question. Please check your question again carefully.

Comment: Sure , thanks. I apologise for nitpicking.